# Page not found error on django when try to upload image

Tags: python, django, file-upload

In my Django project, I am trying to register a student. When I submit the registration form on the live server I got a Page not found (404) error. But it working perfectly on my local server. I think I got this problem for upload image because when I try to submit another form without any image it saves on the database perfectly.

This is the exact error I got.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://xxxxx.com/accounts/registration/student/
Raised by:  accounts.views.register_student
Using the URLconf defined in coaching.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

ad/
accounts/
students/
teachers/
admin/
vedios/
[name='landingpage']
error [name='error_page']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, registration/student/, didn't match any of these.
```

This is the URL patterns related to this problem

```
from django.urls import path,include
from accounts import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('registration/student/', views.register_student, name='student_registration'),
    path('registration/teacher/', views.register_teacher, name='teacher_registration'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.logout_view,name="logout")
]
```

And this the view's method for that I got this error.

```
def register_student(request):
    context={}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_student = True
            user.save()
            # login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'accounts/student_register.html',context)
```

And finally, this is the RegistrationForm() method

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """docstring for ."""
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Upload Your Image",widget = forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':"Your Image"}))
    name = forms.CharField(label="Full Name",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Your Full Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address",help_text="We'll never share your email with anyone else.", widget= forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','aria-describedby':'emailHelp','placeholder':'Enter email'}))
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label="Phone Number",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Your Phone Number'}))
    address = forms.CharField(label="Current Address",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Your Current Address'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password",help_text="Don't share your password with others",widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password",help_text="",widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Re-Enter Password'}))


    class Meta:
        """docstring for ."""
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('image','name','email','phone_number','address','password1','password2')
```

This is the html form page I used

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{%url 'student_registration' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field }}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                      <small id="{{field.id_for_label}}" class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="text-center">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Register as student"><a class="btn btn-secondary ml-1" href="{% url 'teacher_registration' %}">Register as teacher</a>
                </div>
              </form>
```

This is my settings.py file if you need this.

```
"""
Django settings for coaching project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'og3h%0!(#zaxic7ap%o5)#pc8%-2a4(+wq0n!8it^0dssbst+('


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'mainadmin',
    'student',
    'teacher',
    'accounts',
    'vedios',
    'classlinks',
    'frontend',
    'notices',
    'notification'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'coaching.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'coaching.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'accejakr_coaching',
        'USER': 'accejakr_coaching',
        'PASSWORD': 'a3w~$Zk%H_TP',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

This is the global URLs patterns of my project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('ad/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('students/', include('student.urls')),
    path('teachers/', include('teacher.urls')),
    path('admin/', include('mainadmin.urls')),
    # path('class/', include('classlinks.urls')),
    path('vedios/', include('vedios.urls')),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    # path('notifications/', include('notify.urls', 'notifications')),

]
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: It looks like you've not registered your accounts app urls.py in the Django project app. In your Django project app, have you added `path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')` ?

It can better if you can share the other urls.py as well.

Comment: Yes, I add this. I added my global URLs patterns in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `settings.py`.

You have to change this code

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

to this code

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This should work OK now.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Django version 3.0.1